# How to make 2/3 width column in Gutenberg

Tags: block-editor, columns

I created a 2 column layout block, gave the columns block a CSS class of `.first-col-2-3`

and added this CSS to my theme:

```
.first-col-2-3 > div:nth-child(1) {background:red;width:67%!important;}

.first-col-2-3:nth-child(2) {width:33%!important;}
```

The result is that the columns stay 50% / 50% width.

But the first one does get a red background.

So the correct column is targeted, yet the width property isn't changing to make the two columms 67% and 33% respectively.

How do I make the column widths change?

I see a way to add a CSS class to the paragraph within each column but that doesn't work either. Any ideas / solutions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a 2 column block layout where 1 block takes up 2 thirds in the block editor using the UI. Adding CSS classes to achieve this is highly unusual and unnecessary

When you add a column block it asks you:

[image]

Resulting in column blocks spaced for thirds:

[image]

Each block has a percentage width in the block settings:

[image]

If you wanted to use the CSS classes from your theme you have several options:

- Build a custom columns block
- Add CSS classes to the column blocks, completely override or remove the block CSS and add in your own

It appears you tried to do the latter, and ran into a 100% pure CSS issue, CSS questions are best asked on stackoverflow (they're offtopic on WPSE as they aren't WordPress questions)

Comment: I'm not seeing that UI come up in WordPress 5.2.5. 

When I click on the block settings I'm not getting column settings, just settings for the objects contained in columns (images, headings, etc.)

Comment: Upon upgrade to 5.3.2 it worked! Thank you.

Comment: You have to have the column block selected, it sounds like you had one of its child/nested blocks selected instead